# How do I replace a device in a zfs pool that is simultaneously attached and detached?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs

I've got a mirrored zfs pool that has a device that needs to be replaced. I've taken the old device offline:

```
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has been taken offline by the administrator.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Online the device using 'zpool online' or replace the device with
        'zpool replace'.
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 7h20m with 0 errors on Mon Feb 15 23:41:23 2016
config:

        NAME                                   STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                             DEGRADED     0     0     0
            16381379971886761370               OFFLINE      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000cca250cedea5
            ST4000DM000-1F2168_Z303WH86-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I try to replace the offlined device:

```
$ sudo zpool replace tank 16381379971886761370 /dev/mapper/HGST_HDN724040ALE640_PK1334PEH1R1JS
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/mapper/HGST_HDN724040ALE640_PK1334PEH1R1JS is part of active pool 'tank'
```

Which suggests that it's already part of a pool, but when I try to detach it from the pool:

```
$ sudo zpool detach tank /dev/mapper/HGST_HDN724040ALE640_PK1334PEH1R1JS
cannot detach /dev/mapper/HGST_HDN724040ALE640_PK1334PEH1R1JS: no such device in pool
```

It looks like it's not actually part of the pool. This seems like the device is part of the pool and /not/ part of the pool at the same time. Any ideas how I might add the device to the 'tank' pool?

Comment: Try here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can get an error like that if the disk you're trying to put into the pool *used to be* part of a ZFS pool.  If you **know** the disk is unused, wipe it with something like `dd bs=1m if=/dev/zero of=/dev/...`.  Or just use the `-f` option.